# Kendo Mobile Dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, kendo-mobile

I am creating a mobile form using Kendo Mobile and jQuery as below:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVwm.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejpw8.png)

I could get the input textboxes correctly aligned in the form. But the dropdownlist looks ugly. It doesnt have a border or doesnt look like a dropdownlist when viewed on a mobile device.

```
 <li>
                    <h4 style="margin:5px;font-size:.92em;margin-left:0px;font-weight:normal;">Date of Birth</h4>
                    <input data-role="datepicker" id="dateOfbirth" />                       
                </li>

                <li>

                <h4 style="font-size:.92em;margin-left:0px;font-weight:normal;">Marital Status</h4>

                    <select id="kk" data-role="dropdownlist">
                            <option value="single">Single</option>
                            <option value="married">Married</option>
                            <option value="widowed">Widowed</option>
                            <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
                            <option value="separated">Separated</option>
                    </select>


                </li>
```

When selecting on the list it brings up the mobile menu correctly. What could be wrong?